# android pdfview strange crash

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

I am trying to use apv [pdfview](https://code.google.com/p/apv/source/checkout), based on mupdf, and everything works fine, but sometimes, when trying to open pdf, it just kill pdf-view-activity, with some strange logs:

```
    1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'SEMC/ST25i_1263-1753/ST25i:4.0.4/6.1.1.B.1.54/ybt3zw:user/release-keys'
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 12730, tid: 12740  >>> com.myapp.android <<<
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000014
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000001  r1 00f8a948  r2 00fc60a0  r3 4c072148
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 00000000  r5 00f8a948  r6 71700001  r7 4c072148
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 50b24c10  r9 48aeaf68  10 00000000  fp 50b24c24
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 408aeca8  sp 50b24bf8  lr 40854c13  pc 534daff4  cpsr 20000010
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  6565726620696e6a  d3  292879726f6d654d
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  011d21b801280168  d5  00fb6868011f4df0
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  014ed130011d22f0  d7  0127296001235f08
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d16 0000000700000001  d17 4164ea9e00000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d20 3f1155e54e7e8408  d21 0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d22 0000000000000000  d23 3fede16b9c24a98f
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d24 3e66376972bea4d0  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 20000012
132-10132/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
132-10132/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c                  SIGNAL_POLL
132-10132/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ Command received: SIGNAL_POLL
132-10132/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ nl80211: survey data missing!
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 0001cff4  /data/data/com.myapp.android/lib/libpdfview2.so (Java_cx_hell_android_lib_pdf_PDF_freeMemory)
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 0001ec70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 00058f2c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 534dafd4 e3a03000 e1a01006 e1a02007 e595c000  .0....... ......
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 534dafe4 e1a04000 e1a00005 e1a0e00f e59cf1b4  .@..............
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 534daff4 e5943014 e3530000 0a000013 e5940004  .0....S.........
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 534db004 eb002e2d e2506000 d5942014 da00000c  -....`P.. ......
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 534db014 e3a05000 e5942014 e1a07005 e7923105  .P... ...p...1..
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40854bf0 68ebfcc3 0f40f013 bf08692b d00450c7  ...h..@.+i...P..
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40854c00 8f5ef3bf f3bf50c7 98018f5f f0072107  ..^..P.._....!..
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40854c10 bdfefe07 4606b5f7 a801460c 46154631  .......F.F..1F.F
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40854c20 f7fd461f 9801fa71 f7fe4621 68ebfca5  .F..q...!F.....h
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40854c30 0f40f013 bf08692b d00450c7 8f5ef3bf  ..@.+i...P....^.
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bb8  408b0f9c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bbc  4c072148  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bc0  71700001
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bc4  4085359b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bc8  71700001
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bcc  4c072148  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bd0  00f8a948  [heap]
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bd4  40854c13  /system/lib/libdvm.so
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bd8  00f8a948  [heap]
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bdc  00fc60a0  [heap]
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24be0  4c072148  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24be4  00000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24be8  00f8a948  [heap]
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bec  71700001
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bf0  df0027ad
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bf4  00000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 50b24bf8  4c072208  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24bfc  00fc60a0  [heap]
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c00  00000000
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c04  48aeaf70
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c08  50b24c10
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c0c  4081cc74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 50b24c10  48aeaf64
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c14  00000001
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c18  42801948  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c1c  00fc60b0  [heap]
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c20  00000002
1041-1041/? I/DEBUG﹕ 50b24c24  40856f2f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
132-10132/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
132-10132/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c                  SIGNAL_POLL
132-10132/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ Command received: SIGNAL_POLL
132-10132/? D/wpa_supplicant﹕ nl80211: survey data missing!
730-12730/? V/cx.hell.android.pdfview﹕ 0
730-12730/? V/cx.hell.android.pdfview﹕ 2
1790-1835/? I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_08 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
790-15133/? I/WindowManager﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{41556e08 com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activities.HomeActivity paused=false}
1790-1801/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.myapp.android (pid 12730) has died.
1790-1801/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.myapp.android/.web.myappSpiceService in 5000ms
1417-1417/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 12730 terminated by signal (11)
1790-1801/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{413e0100 com.myapp.android/.activities.PdfViewActivity}: app died, no saved state
1790-1850/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4192f8e0 com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activities.SubscriptionIssuesActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
1790-1850/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4192f8e0 com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activities.SubscriptionIssuesActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
1790-2124/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4192f8e0 com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activities.SubscriptionIssuesActivity (server)'
1790-2124/? I/WindowManager﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{4192f8e0 com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activities.SubscriptionIssuesActivity paused=false}
790-10967/? I/WindowManager﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{41a4e870 Toast paused=false}
790-19923/? I/WindowManager﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{41d109c8 com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activities.PdfViewActivity paused=false}
1416-1652/? I/libblt_hw﹕ Library closed (handle = 14, fd = 62)
1790-1850/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
1790-1850/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
1790-1850/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
1790-1850/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropping event because there is no touched window or focused application.
1790-1850/? I/WindowManager﹕ WINDOW DIED Window{4192f8e0 com.myapp.android/com.myapp.android.activities.SubscriptionIssuesActivity paused=false}
232-13232/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
```

I am using android 4.0.4.
Any advices?

**EDIT**
I found, that app crashes sometimes when finalize by gc called  on PDF object

```
    synchronized private native void freeMemory();

public void finalize() {
    try {
        super.finalize();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
    this.freeMemory();
}
```

Comment: Does this happen with particular pdf documents, and other pdf documents are okay? Do you know what version of mupdf you are using?

Comment: No, this happens no matter what pdf files was opened, usually after open different files several times, as described here https://code.google.com/p/apv/issues/detail?id=137 
I also found out version of mupdf is 0.8 (my project kind of legacy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mupdf 0.8 is pretty old unfortunately.

I think it's likely you'd find this was fixed if you upgrade to 1.6 - as well as general bug fixes, the 1.6 release also contains a number of Android specific bug fixes & improvements.